# Cannot convert DataFrame to series data for plotting in julia

Tags: julia

I'm learning julia from https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/basics/
Here is the julia code

```
using Plots,UnicodePlots,RDatasets
unicodeplots()
v=dataset("Ecdat","Airline")
typeof(v)
plot(v, :Cost) # this line will produce the error
plot(v) # this line will produce the error, too
```

I got

```
ERROR: Cannot convert DataFrame to series data for plotting
Stacktrace:
 [1] prepareSeriesData(::DataFrame) at /home/dlin/.julia/packages/Plots/qZHsp/src/series.jl:14
 [2] convertToAnyVector(::DataFrame, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}) at /home/dlin/.julia/packages/Plots/qZHsp/src/series.jl:26
 [3] macro expansion at /home/dlin/.julia/packages/Plots/qZHsp/src/series.jl:130 [inlined]
 [4] apply_recipe(::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Type{Plots.SliceIt}, ::Nothing, ::DataFrame, ::Nothing) at /home/dlin/.julia/packages/RecipesBase/zBoFG/src/RecipesBase.jl:275
 [5] _process_userrecipes(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Tuple{DataFrame}) at /home/dlin/.julia/packages/Plots/qZHsp/src/pipeline.jl:83
 [6] _plot!(::Plots.Plot{Plots.GRBackend}, ::Dict{Symbol,Any}, ::Tuple{DataFrame}) at /home/dlin/.julia/packages/Plots/qZHsp/src/plot.jl:178
 [7] #plot#138(::Base.Iterators.Pairs{Union{},Union{},Tuple{},NamedTuple{(),Tuple{}}}, ::typeof(plot), ::DataFrame) at /home/dlin/.julia/packages/Plots/qZHsp/src/plot.jl:57
 [8] plot(::DataFrame) at /home/dlin/.julia/packages/Plots/qZHsp/src/plot.jl:51
 [9] top-level scope at REPL[4]:1
```

In the code of series.jl, it is

```
prepareSeriesData(x) = error("Cannot convert $(typeof(x)) to series data for plotting")
```

How to correct this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That part of the docs might be outdated. You have to use `StatsPlots` and the `@df` macro to get the desired behavior.

```
julia> using StatsPlots

julia> @df v plot(:Cost)
                      ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐   
         4.88870026e6 │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣠⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│ y1
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⢹⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡎⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡸⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠎⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⠃⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡎⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡎⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⠁⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⡸⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⠁⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⢀⠇⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⡼⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⡆⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⢣⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⡰⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⢰⠁⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⡰⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⢠⠇⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⡰⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⢀⠇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠜⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡏⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⡎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠜⠊⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠎⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡄⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⡼⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⠋⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡎⠀⠀⢱⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡜⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⡠⠒⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⢀⠜⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠔⢲⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡔⠁⠀⠀│   
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠸⠒⠊⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⡠⠖⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⢀⡠⠒⠁⠀⠈⡆⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠎⠀⠀⠀⠀│   
   -71402.26000000001 │⠤⡧⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠭⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠼⠶⠾⠭⠥⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠷⠶⠾⠭⠭⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤│   
                      └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘   
                      -1.67                                                    92.67
```

This is explained in later sections of the manual: https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/input_data/#dataframes-support

Comment: That line in the manual says "... must import StatsPlots". Maybe that is too unclear? What could we write instead?

Comment: using StatsPlots is not the issue. The issue is the syntax that the docs give (ie `plot(dataset("Ecdat", "Airline"), :Cost)`) throws an error. It seems that syntax should instead by replaced by `@df v plot(:Cost)`

Comment: Of course, thanks. I've updated the docs https://github.com/JuliaPlots/PlotDocs.jl/commit/497418e8d0e2aeca62798ad3dab90da2c9ead954

Comment: I choose this answer, because it also provide group usage, that's important for display this example data.  It is better to put the group in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

What about simply using `plot(v.Cost)`:

```
julia> plot(v.Cost)
                      ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
         4.88870026e6 │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣠⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│ y1
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣿⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⢹⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⡄⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡎⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡸⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠎⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⠃⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡎⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡎⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⠁⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⡸⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢰⠁⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⢀⠇⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⡼⠀⠀⠀⠀⠈⡆⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⢣⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⡰⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⢰⠁⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⡰⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⢠⠇⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⡰⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⢀⠇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⣀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠜⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡏⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⡎⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠜⠊⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢀⠎⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡄⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⡼⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⢠⠋⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡎⠀⠀⢱⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡜⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠋⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⡠⠒⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⢀⠜⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠔⢲⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡔⠁⠀⠀│
                      │⠀⡇⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠸⠒⠊⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⠀⡇⡠⠖⠉⠁⠀⠀⠀⠀⢸⠀⠀⠀⢀⡠⠒⠁⠀⠈⡆⠀⠀⠀⠀⡠⠎⠀⠀⠀⠀│
   -71402.26000000001 │⠤⡧⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠭⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠼⠶⠾⠭⠥⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠷⠶⠾⠭⠭⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤⠤│
                      └────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
                      -1.67                                                    92.67
```